# Xdebug 2 does not appear in phpinfo()

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug

I need Xdebug version 2, not 3.

I used this link to install Xdebug: https://2.xdebug.org/docs/install

After doing all cases I can see Xdebug via `php -v` command :

[image: php -v]

But in `phpinfo()` output Xdebug is absent:

[image: phpinfo()]

Can you please suggest me how to resolve this issue?

php.ini settings:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port="9000"
```

It's present in `/usr/lib`:

[image: /usr/lib]

Comment: Check what php.ini config file it uses. On Linxu and Mac it is very common to have **separate** php.ini for CLI (terminal) and web server (FPM / Apache). Your `phpinfo()` screenshot shows that it uses FPM one. Check the same in your terminal (e.g. `php --ini`) -- I bet it will be different set of file. If that's the case -- edit correct config file that is used by your web server and restart it.

Comment: Please post text and not images - images are very hard to read.